# How to access socket.io client id from controller NestJS?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I'm developing chat support on webhooks. I use chat aggregator and it is not my personal service. So, every time any message comes from support I receive it in my controller, and the task is to pass this message to my client via `websockets`. The problem is that I cannot send message to a specific socket, so I need to know its id.
Having the following code:

```
@Controller('chat')
export class ChatController {
    @UseInterceptors(CamelCaseConverterInterceptor)
    @Post()
    getExternalMessage(
        @Body() payload: WebhookChatMessageDto,
        @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
    ): void {
       ... code
    }
}
```

I wish to get current socket client id, but it seems like `@ConnectedSocket()` decorator doesn't work within controllers. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you do not need use decorator in your controller methods. First parameter is socket, second is payload. So in your method:

```js
getExternalMessage(
        client: Socket,
        payload: WebhookChatMessageDto,
    ): void {
       console.log(client.id); //client id
       client.emit(...); //emit to this client
    }
```

but if you want to use websocket endpoints, this should not to be @Post() but use @SubscribeMessage('someMessage'). In post request you will never will be able to access to socket client, because this is communication thgrough different port, and you cannot pair post request with users socket.io connection

Comment: this code doesn't seem to work (I cant remove `@Post` decorator since an external source sends `post` request to me). So, if I can't access to socket instance within the controller -- what should I do?

Comment: no, I didn't said that :) You CAN access to socket instance in your backend. But you cant find client's socket.io clientId. If you have to implement this post route, you need to add extra parameter, where client send his client ID. Than this parameter will not be Socket, but simple string. And you must find proper client from your socket by this string

Comment: What do you mean? I removed `@ConnectedSocket()` decorator and it seems like client param gets undefined. If don't do this I receive wrong instance (IncomingMessage instance)...

Comment: just remove client param from your method. It will be `getExternalMessage(@Body() payload: WebhookChatMessageDto)` and extend WebhookChatMessageDto adding new key, for example socketId: string. This must send frontend to your backend. After that, you need to find this socketId in your socket server instance for getting client instance

Comment: no-no-no, `external source/message` -- it's chat aggregator and *is not* my service at all. I can't send socket id from this service because I do not have any permission on that. *My* frontend side also cannot send request to this endpoint because of my cors policy.

Comment: how do you pass socket instance from the controller?