# How to pass socket client connection from nestjs service

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I want to pass the connected socket client to nest js service. I referred to this question
 [https://stackoverflow.com/question....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242522/how-to-access-socket-io-client-id-from-controller-nestjs).but I can't understand how to pass the `client:Socket` from my service.

I have a bull queue which handles some file processing tasks. once the file processing is completed. I want to notify that to the user who sent that file. below is my WebSocket gateway. In here `notifyJobStatus` is getting called once the job is done. but I want to send it to a particular client. for that, I need to access the client from my service. then I can modify the method to something like this `notifyJobStatus(status: string, client: Socket)`.please correct me if this approach is wrong.

```
export class NotificationsService
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(NotificationsService.name);

  notifyJobStatus(status: string) {
    //client.broadcast.to(client.id).emit('JobStatus', status);
    this.server.emit('JobStatus', status);
  }

  afterInit() {
    this.logger.log('Websocket Server Started,Listening on Port:3006');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me, It should work for you also.
Let's say we have **notifyModule** and I want to call the queue in **OrderModule**

1. I exported the **NotifyConsumer** in the module
2. I then registered the queue in the  Order Module, don't forget, it's registered in your NotifyModule also.

```
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'order-queue',
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'notify-queue',
    }),
```

Note: The **order-queue** has nothing to do with the answer, I just copied my code for you.

Then, I imported the **notify-queue** in the order controller file that I needed it

```
    @InjectQueue('notify-queue') private notifyQueue: Queue,
```

Lastly, I used it and it worked

```
    // send latest notification
      await this.notifyQueue.add('notify', {
        ...
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your gateway, I guess it is not setup properly. Gateway in nestjs takes the form below:

```js
@WebSocketGateway()
export class NotificationsService
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(NotificationsService.name);

  @SubscribeMessage('event to listen to')
  notifyJobStatus(status: string) {
    //client.broadcast.to(client.id).emit('JobStatus', status);
    this.server.emit('JobStatus', status);
  }

  afterInit() {
    this.logger.log('Websocket Server Started,Listening on Port:3006');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, since you are using a bull queue to process the job, you can emit the job status from the bull queue consumer that processes the job, which    @SubscribeMessage('event to listen to') will listen on, and the notifyJobStatus method will be called to send the status to the user.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this `i guess it is not setup properly?`

Comment: @NicoleZ, how did you get it done?

Comment: @Oluwatobiloba Couldn't find a solution for this.if you find something please add it here

Comment: I actually found a way to do on my end, let me make it an answer

Comment: @NicoleZ check my answer i forgot to tag you